# Dropbox AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Dropbox'

Tags: python, dropbox

I'm new to python. I wanna try the easiest example of the dropbox.

```
import dropbox
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox('access_token')
dbx.users_get_current_account()
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Peezy/Desktop/test.py", line 2, in <module>
    dbx = dropbox.Dropbox('access_token')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Dropbox'
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/Peezy/Desktop/test.py"]
[dir: /Users/Peezy/Desktop]
[path: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/aria2/bin:/opt/X11/bin]
```

It seems to me that the python didn't find my dropbox library. I've already installed dropbox correctly with "sudo pip install dropbox" (at least I think so). How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Do you have a file of your own named 'dropbox.py' by any chance?

Comment: @Greg No, as you can see, my code names test.py

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but I was asking if you happened to have _another_ file named dropbox.py. If you do, that would be imported (and presumably not have an attribute `Dropbox`).

Comment: @Greg on the desktop there is no file name dropbox.py.

Comment: Try these after `import`ing `dropbox` then: `print(dropbox.__file__)` and `print(dropbox.__version__)`.

Comment: @Greg it gives me the following stuffs     /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dropbox-2.2.0-py2.7.egg/dropbox/__init__.pyc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Peezy/Desktop/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(dropbox.__version__)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__version__'

Comment: It appears you have a relatively old version of the Dropbox library, which doesn't have that `Dropbox` attribute. You have 2.2.0, but [the latest version](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python/releases) is currently 8.4.1. What output did you get from `sudo pip install dropbox`? Perhaps try `sudo pip install --upgrade dropbox`.

Comment: @Greg if I run sudo pip install dropbox, it returns: `Requirement already satisfied: dropbox in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dropbox-2.2.0-py2.7.egg Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from dropbox)`

Comment: Thanks! That does confirm you only have an old version. Please try with `--upgrade`.

Comment: @Greg thanks! it works!